# Shell script, escape newlines but emit others?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, tr

Given a filename, I want to write a shell-script which emits the following, and pipes it into a process:

```
Content-Length:<LEN><CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "params":{ "text":"<ESCAPED-TEXT>" } }
```

where `<ESCAPED-TEXT>` is the content of the file but its CRs, LFs and quotation marks have been escaped as `\r` and `\n` and `\"` (and I guess all other JSON escapes will eventually be needed as well), and where `<LEN>` is the length of final JSON line that includes the escaped text.

Here's my current bash-script solution. It works but is ugly as heck.

```
(
  TXT=`cat ~/a.py | sed -E -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/\\\n/g; ta' | sed 's/"/\\\"/g'`
  CMD='{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "params":{ "text":{"'${TXT}'"}} }'
  printf "Content-Length: ${#CMD}\r\n\r\n"
  echo -n "${CMD}"
) | pyls
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this cleaner, please?

- This sed script only replaces LFs, not CRs. It accumulates each line into the buffer and then does a `s//g` to replace all LFs in it. I couldn't figure out anything cleaner that still worked on both Linux and OSX/BSD.
- I used both printf and echo. First **printf** because I *do* want to emit the CRLFCRLF after the Content-Length header, and you apparently need printf for that because the behavior of echo with escapes isn't uniform across platforms. Next **echo** because I *don't* want the `\r` and `\n` literals inside TXT to be unescaped, which printf would do.

Context: there's a standard called "Language Server Protocol". Basically you run something like the `pyls` I'm running here, and you pipe in JsonRPC to it over stdin, and it pipes back stuff. Different people have written language servers for Python (the pyls I'm using here), and C#, and C++, and Typescript, and PHP, and OCaml, and Go, and Java, and each person tends to write their language server in their own language.

I want to write a test-harness which can send some example JsonRPC packets into any such server.

I figured it'd be better to write my test-harness in just the common basic shell-scripting stuff that's available on all platforms out of the box. That way everyone can use my test-harness against their language server. (If I wrote it on Python instead, say, it'd be easier for me to write, but it would force the C# folks to learn+install python just to run it, and likewise the Typescript, PHP, OCaml, Go and other folks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.py:

```
print("alfa")
print("bravo")
```

Awk script:

```
{
  gsub("\r", "\\r")
  gsub("\42", "\\\42")
  z = z $0 "\\n"
}
END {
  printf "Content-Length: %d\r\n", length(z) + 42
  printf "\r\n"
  printf "{\42jsonrpc\42: \0422.0\42, \42params\42: {\42text\42: \42%s\42}}", z
}
```

Result:

```
Content-Length: 81

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"text": "print(\"alfa\")\r\nprint(\"bravo\")\r\n"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem with your script is not using format strings with printf.  The usual way that printf is used is with various special characters in the *format string* (like `%s`, `%b`, etc) and a list of additional arguments that are substituted into the format string.

That is, when you say "[I used] echo because I don't want the \r and \n literals to be unescaped, which printf would do", the problem is just not using `printf "%s" "$string"`.

Anyway, here's an idea of how to use this stuff to get everything done in bash with no external tools:

```
escapes=('\n' '\r' '\"')         # the escapes we want to put into the output

txt=$(< ~/a.py);                 # read the file into a variable
for esc in "${escapes[@]}"; do
    # escapes are evaluated in a %b string w/ printf
    # using -v puts the result into a variable
    printf -v lit '%b' "$esc"
    # use built-in ${string//pattern/replacement} expansion
    txt=${txt//$lit/$esc}
done

txt='{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "params":{ "text":{"'$txt'"}} }'

# escapes in the format string are expanded
# but escapes in the argument substituted for %s are not
printf 'Content-Length: %s\r\n\r\n%s' "${#txt}" "$txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone suggest how to do this cleaner, please?
>
> I guess all other JSON escapes will eventually be needed as well

If I already had Python at my disposal, I'd try really, really hard to use the standard [Python JSON encoder](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html), at least for the string escaping part.  Why hack together something that kind of works when you can use something known to work that you already are halfway familiar with?

If I didn't have Python, I like [Steve Penny's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080117/451601) solution.  Rules of thumb:

1. to process sets of files, use the shell
2. to process data in a file, use awk
3. if sed can't do it trivially, see rule #2

If you know a little awk, his solution is easy to understand almost at a glance.  I would call that "cleaner".  If you don't know awk, this would seem to be an excellent opportunity to become acquainted.